# How do I insert record in to VendorPricesInquiry in Acumatica over REST API?

Tags: acumatica

I am submitting this data over PUT method (shooting in the dark)

```
{
    'InventoryID': {'value': 'Telecommunications'}, 
    'VendorID': {'value': 'Telecom NZ'}, 
    'VendorPriceDetails': [{'Price': {'value': 1234.00}}], 
    'UOM': {'value': 'EACH'}
}
```

and I got this error

```
{
    'message': 'An error has occurred.', 
    'exceptionMessage': "Inserting  'AP Vendor Price' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.\nVendorID: 'Vendor' cannot be empty.\nInventoryID: 'Inventory ID' cannot be empty.\nUOM: 'UOM' cannot be empty.\nPX.Data.PXOuterException: Inserting  'AP Vendor Price' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors....'
}
```

I couldn't find any relevant doc about inserting into `VendorPricesInquiry` so not sure what data structure I should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my structure is fine, it's just that the item doesn't exist anymore, the error message was very misleading.